# how can i merge all worksheets into single worksheet in excel

Tags: vba, excel

i have a xlsx file with multiple sheets, i need to combine all sheets in this file into a single sheet, and append the sheet name in result

```
sheets :[class A, class B]
class A sheet
id  Name
1   a1
2   a2

class B sheet
id  Name
1   b1
2   b2
```

what i want is to merge all and use sheet name as 3rd columns so result sheet would be

```
All sheet:
id  Name  sheet_name
1    a1   class A
2    a2   class A
1    b1   class B
2    b2   class B
```

how can i do such merge in excel ?

Comment: Check the [Consolidate data from multiple sheets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b) article at Microsoft Support. For your 3rd column you might want to add that column with constant sheet-name in each of your source sheets.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this code:

```
Sub main()
    Dim isht As Long
    Dim allSht As Worksheet
    Dim dataArr As Variant
    Dim shtName As String

    Set allSht = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

    For isht = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
        With Worksheets(isht)
            dataArr = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:B")).Value
            shtName = .Name
        End With
        With allSht
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .Resize(UBound(dataArr, 1), UBound(dataArr, 2)).Value = dataArr
                .Offset(, 2) = "sheet_name"
                .Offset(1, 2).Resize(UBound(dataArr, 1) - 1).Value = shtName
            End With
        End With
    Next isht

    With allSht
        .Rows(1).Delete
        .Name = "All"
    End With
End Sub
```